# How to fetch data from ASP .Net Web API in Bootstrap Datagrid (bs_grid)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datagrid, asp.net-web-api

**I am trying to use an ASP .Net Web API 2 function to fill the Bootstrap Datagrid plugin.** My Web API function works perfectly when I test it using a normal jQuery Ajax call. **But when I put the URL into the plugin script, the list is always empty and the datagrid does not work.** Here is my bs_grid script:

```
<pre>
function generateCandidatesList(currentURL) {
    var apiURL = currentURL + "/api/candidates";

    $("#candidatesList").bs_grid({
        ajaxFetchDataURL: apiURL,
        pageNum: 1,
        rowsPerPage: 10,
        maxRowsPerPage: 20,
        rowSelectionMode: "single", // "multiple", "single", false
        row_primary_key: "MemberID",

        columns: [
            { field: "MemberID", header: "MemberID", visible: "no" },
            { field: "FirstName", header: "First Name" },
            { field: "LastName", header: "Last Name" },
            { field: "EMailAddress", header: "Email Address" }
        ]

    });
}
</pre>
```

And here is my Web API function:

```
<pre>
[RoutePrefix("API")]
    public class CandidatesController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("Candidates")]
        [HttpGet]
        public JToken GetCandidates()
        {
            List<CandidateModel> candidatesList = new List<CandidateModel>();
            DBActions dbActions = new DBActions();
            JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            QueryResult queryResult = dbActions.Site.GetCandidates();
            if (queryResult.Exception == null)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dataRow in queryResult.Data.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    candidatesList.Add(new CandidateModel
                    {
                        MemberID = dataRow["MemberID"].ToString(),
                        FirstName = dataRow["FirstName"].ToString(),
                        LastName = dataRow["LastName"].ToString(),
                        EMailAddress = dataRow["EMailAddress"].ToString(),
                        PermanentLinkName = dataRow["PermanentLinkName"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }

            CandidatesListModel candidates = new CandidatesListModel
            {
                row_primary_key = "MemberID",
                total_rows = candidatesList.Count.ToString(),
                page_data = candidatesList.ToArray()
            };

            return JObject.Parse(javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(candidates));
        }
    }
</pre>
```

When I test the above API function using the following Ajax call, it works and returns a Json string:

```
<pre>
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: apiURL,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Error"); }
    });
</pre>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0):

The default HTTP method for bs_grid ajaxFetchDataURL is POST. Your server side code handles [HttpGet]. Currently more options is not available for bs_grid ajax call. There is an issue on it on [Github](https://github.com/pontikis/bs_grid/issues/4)